# Creating list of date and time between two input dates

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

This might be a very simple problem, but I am spending a lot of time to resolve this. I have a code like this :

```
st_date=parser.parse(start_date)
en_date=parser.parse(end_date)

sel=[np.datetime64(st_date)+np.timedelta64(xx,'h') for xx in range(0,(diff.days*24+diff.seconds/3600))]
```

This generates the list of the date and time, but time starting time is the current time, I would like to start my time as 01:00  and end time as 23:00.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: This code is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can truncate your `st_date` to hours before generating the sequence:

```
st_date = st_date.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

---

For instance, if you use the built-in `datetime` module:

```
import datetime

# initialize the start and end date
st_date = datetime.datetime.now()
en_date = st_date + datetime.timedelta(days = 2.2)
diff = en_date - st_date

# truncate the start date to hours
st_date = st_date.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

# generate sequence
sel=[st_date + datetime.timedelta(hours = xx) for xx in range(0, diff.days*24 + diff.seconds/3600)]

sel

#[datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 29, 21, 0),
# datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 29, 22, 0),
# datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 29, 23, 0),
# datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 0, 0),
# datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 1, 0),
# datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 2, 0),
# datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 3, 0),
# datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 4, 0),
# datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 5, 0),
# datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 6, 0),
# datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 7, 0),
# datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 8, 0),
# ...]
```